# "–maybe that's how the tunnel I got into..."

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the story "The Third Level", by Jack Finney, what does the narrator mean by "–maybe that's how the tunnel I got into..."

Is it a typo? On the other hand, I can't seem to find the correct version online. This is what I got from my [textbook](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/levt101.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiv-OfJssT0AhWyzoUKHS2RD-oQFnoECDcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1tYs_ADIxNhsTKAACK5SwY) online.

Context

> I turned into Grand Central from Vanderbilt Avenue,
> and went down the steps to the first level, where you take
> trains like the Twentieth Century. Then I walked down
> another flight to the second level, where the suburban trains
> leave from, ducked into an arched doorway heading for the
> subway — and got lost. That’s easy to do. I’ve been in and
> out of Grand Central hundreds of times, but I’m always
> bumping into new doorways and stairs and corridors. Once
> I got into a tunnel about a mile long and came out in the
> lobby of the Roosevelt Hotel. Another time I came up in an
> office building on Forty-sixth Street, three blocks away.

> Sometimes I think Grand Central is growing like a
> tree, pushing out new corridors and staircases like roots.There’s probably a long tunnel that nobody knows about feeling its way under the city right now, on its way to Times Square, and maybe another to Central Park. And maybe — because for so many people through the years Grand Central has been an exit, a way of escape **— maybe that’s how the tunnel I got into...** But I never told
> my psychiatrist friend about that
> idea.

Both paragraphs are together and not separate. And while the phrase is in the second paragraph, I added the first one for more context

Comment: The ellipsis after 'into' is suggestive of an unfinished thought. Have you considered what that might be?

Comment: @Michael Woke Harvey hmm... so you are saying the narrator deliberately stopped. I think that makes sense.  Immediately after the sentence, the narrator says "but I never told my psychiatrist friend about that idea", maybe that implies he is embarrassed of his ideas which is why he quickly stopped

Comment: I'm sure you are right. He imagines the tunnels growing of their own accord.

Comment: The idea of spontaneously growing tunnels would probably be interesting to a psychiatrist. It certainly seems to interest the novelist, who could perhaps be, in a way, the character's 'psychiatrist'. Characters can have inner states. I have had dreams like that.